# ¿Cómo puedo crear las líneas horizontales con CSS como se muestra en la imagen?

Tags: css

¿Cómo puedo crear lineas horizontales con CSS?

Adjunto imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues supongo que te refieres a <hr>, se hacen des de HTML. Luego en el CSS podrás darle estilo si quieres

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer, la solución será una u otra. Por favor, concreta tu pregunta, añade algo de contexto (y código si es posible) y aclara qué es lo que tiene que tener una línea horizontal. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ese diseno se puede hacer de muchas maneras todo depende de lo que quieras hacer pero te dejo un ekemplo de mas o menos como se podria hacer podrias usar etiquetas **hr** tambien para lograrlo pero bueno todo depende.

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
.dark div{
  
  border-bottom:solid 1px grey;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dark">
  <div>

  </div>
   <div>

  </div>
   <div>

  </div>
   <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Las puedes usar añadiendo `<hr>` en tu codigo HTMl.

Luego puedes en `css` puedes editarlo a tu gusto:

Por ejemplo:

```css
/*CSS */

hr {
border: 0;
border-top: 2px solid #999; 
border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
height:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<hr>
```

Pagina con algunos [ejemplos](https://www.oloblogger.com/2013/01/estilo-css-para-division-hr.html):

Answer (score 0):

Amigo las puedes poner con la etiqueta "hr" con sus respectivos < y > desde html y modificarla en css tipo:

> hr {
>      height: 2px;
>      background-color: black; 
>   }